# Program is working but with error, String index out of range: -1

Tags: java

this is my first post in here, btw, my teacher has given the class an assignment in programming in which we need to do a palindrome program, i'm able to do it but i wanted to get rid of the error, can you please explain me why there's an error, and how do I get rid of it?

```
import java.io.*;

public class AssignmentInCopro 

{public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
    {BufferedReader x = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String word = "";

    System.out.print("Please enter the word you want to see in reverse: ");
    word = x.readLine();

    int wordLength = word.length(); 

    while (wordLength >=0)
    {
    char letter = word.charAt(wordLength - 1);
    System.out.print(letter);
    wordLength--;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the condition to `wordLength > 0` (without the =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes while your loop includet the index zero. If the `wordLength` is zero so you will look for the `charAt(-1)` and you get the exception:

Change your code to:

```
while (wordLength >0)
```

And the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

```
 while (wordLength >=0)
```

this cause error when wordLength =0 then `char letter = word.charAt(wordLength - 1);` is actually char `letter = word.charAt(0 - 1);`

```
while (wordLength >0)
```

This should be condition or you can write your loop like this -

```
int wordLength = word.length() - 1;
while (wordLength >=0){
    System.out.print(word.charAt(wordLength--));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look what happens when wordlength is actually equals to 0 //while (wordLength >=0)
you trying to access char at -1 //word.charAt(wordLength - 1);

change it with while (wordLength >0) or while (wordLength >=1)

Have a nice day